# JQuery click event fires 60 times

Tags: jquery, events, click

The problem is that I have a page with 60 elements, which are exactly the same:

```
<div class="imagetd">...</div>
<div class="imagetd">...</div>
....
<div class="imagetd">...</div>
<div class="imagetd">...</div>
```

And an event for them:

```
$('.imagetd').each(function(){
   var that = this;
   $(that).on('click', function(){
      console.log('clicked!');
   })
});
```

I also tried the following

```
$(document).on('click', '.imagetd', function(e){
   console.log('clicked!');
});
```

When I click on any of that elements the event fires 60 times. Could you tell me please why? And how to fix it?

Comment: Why you have `.each`? Also you can use `$(this)` straight away

Comment: @Mr.Alien but that is not the problem right?

Comment: can you provide some more context regarding where you have this code

Comment: Each is not the problem at all.

Comment: looks like the code you have given is executed 60 times.... c

Comment: can you add a console statement before the each and see how many times it is executed

Comment: More code. Looks like you bind event more then once.

Comment: @ArunPJohny nope, infact code never iterates 60 times, it works as it should...

Comment: seems ok **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/CrZ6y/)**..@ArunPJohny It will work in both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the each function to apply an event handler to multiple items. This should work:

```
$('.imagetd').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked!');
});
```

Comment: This is the same. Internally jQuery still uses `each` method.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `each`, it runs based on the count of the elements, if you have 60 elements it runs that much time.

```
$(function(){        
     $(document).on('click', '.imagetd', function(e){
         console.log('clicked!');
      });   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.imagetd').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked!');
    $(this).die('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U655V/), it works fine without

```
$.each
```

You can directly bind to a collection of elements, no need for using each, though it's not the cause.